# Instance of same fragment destroy layout of first one in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to fetch results from sqllite db in ViewPager using Adapater class

```
public class AppDetailPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<AppPagingData> mData;


    public AppDetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<AppPagingData> data) {
        super(fm);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        sCurrentPosition = i;
        Fragment fragment = AppDetailFragment.newInstance(mData, i);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

And my fragment is

```
public class AppDetailFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private List<AppPagingData> mData;
private int mCurrentPosition;
private int mToken;

private static final String EXTRA_KEY_APP_DATA = "EXTRA_KEY_APP_DATA";
private static final String EXTRA_KEY_APP_CURR_POSITION = "EXTRA_KEY_APP_CURR_POSITION";


public static AppDetailFragment newInstance(ArrayList<AppPagingData> param1, int currentPosition) {
    AppDetailFragment fragment = new AppDetailFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(EXTRA_KEY_APP_DATA, param1);
    args.putInt(EXTRA_KEY_APP_CURR_POSITION, currentPosition);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public AppDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(mToken, null, this);
} 
 @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (loader.getId() == mToken) {
        ViewGroup oocsGroup = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.oocsGroup);

        // Remove all existing timings (except 1 ie header)
        //I think this line remove childs for all fragment????
        for (int i = oocsGroup.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            oocsGroup.removeViewAt(i);
        }

    } else {
        cursor.close();
    }
}...
```

Now, the problem is my fragment linear layout items get deleted, as android call my fragment second instance. for e.g. if i select 1st item second will called automatically.

How to avoid layout of first instance to destry because of second.

Comment: it looks like `private List<AppPagingData> data;` should be `private List<AppPagingData> mData;`

Answer (score 0):

As your adapter creates a new instance of fragment at `getItem()`, you are probably loosing the previous fragment to the garbage collector.

You could keep your fragments in an array (or ArrayList) and return fragment from the array at `getItem()`.

like:

```
// keep created instances of AppDetailFragments
private AppDetailFragment[] frags;

public AppDetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<AppPagingData> data) {
    super(fm);
    this.data = data;
    frags = new AppDetailFragment[data.size()];

    // init all frags
    for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++) {
       frags[i] = AppDetailFragment.newInstance(data, i);
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    sCurrentPosition = i;
    return frags[i]; // may want to check for arrayindexoutofboundsEx..
}
```

This way you will keep a reference to all created fragments.

note:
You no longer need to keep the `data` as for `getCount` you can return length of frags-array.

Comment: I tried your sol with no effect. I think problem is onLoadFinished method of fragment

Comment: Without the layout file it's hard to know what effect `oocsGroup.removeViewAt(i);` does. What are you trying to accomplish in `onLoadFinished`?

Comment: it's a simple `LinearLayout` in which i am adding `ImageView` dynamically onLoadFinished